# How to filter database results by nearness of gps location?

Tags: php, android, mysql, gps, location

I'm getting a GPS location via an android app and then asking the server which of the records in the database are near it.

How can I accomplish this?

Let's say that these are the coordinates:

```
39.017411, -97.251117
```

How can I ask the database in PHP to only give me the results that contain coordinates near those?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: can you add your table structure and schema here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like as mentioned below, considering field name of your table is `lat` for latitude and `lng` for longitude

```
$lat = 39.017411;
$lng = -97.251117;

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT tbl.id, tbl.lat, tbl.lng, 111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS($lat))
 * COS(RADIANS(lat))
 * COS(RADIANS(lng) - RADIANS($lng))
 + SIN(RADIANS($lat))
 * SIN(RADIANS(lat))))
 AS distance_in_km
FROM table_name as tbl
ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC
LIMIT 0,1");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
        echo $row[lat].";".$row[lng];
    }
```

Comment: Great answer! Everything worked beautifully!